# MySQL - What exactly does smallint(2) permit?

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the really simple question, but I can't figure it out.

When I set up my schema, I set up my primary key to use a field of type `smallint(2)`. The thought behind it was that the field should only ever consist of 2-digit numbers, 1-99.

We've broken the upper limit of that and now I'm seeing 3-digit numbers being added to this field. I'm now speculating that `smallint(2)` and `varchar(2)` do not function the same, but since I don't understand what's going on with this table I'm getting a little concerned.

What values does a field such as `smallint(2)` allow?

Thanks!

Comment: It allows the same values as any other `SMALLINT`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37195/tinyint-structure-is-confusing - same question, other way around (`tinyint(3)`).

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this should be closed as a duplicate. The docs for smallint don't offer any clue about what smalling(2) might mean, and there's only one *relatively* similar question in my sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html), the `(n)` suffix for numeric types is the (default) display width for numbers in that column. In your case the `(2)` sets the default display width to 2 digits. It does not *limit* numbers in that column to two digits (as you have discovered), it's just a formatting hint for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It's used just for display AND when zerofill is enabled, it will basically add left zeros if you data has less digits than specified. in your case, it will add 0's if your number has less then 2 characters length.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE zero_fill;
+-------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a     | tinyint(2)                   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| b     | tinyint(2) unsigned zerofill | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> INSERT INTO zero_fill SET a=1, b=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO zero_fill SET a=11, b=11;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO zero_fill SET a=111, b=111;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
mysql> SELECT * FROM zero_fill;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |  001 |
|   11 |   11 |
|  111 |  111 |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, smallint(2) doesn't do what you think it does.

In MySQL, the best way to guarantee two-digit numbers is to build a table, insert all the valid two-digit numbers, and set a foreign key reference to it.